# Elevate user rights in XP for dependency installation

Tags: installation, windows-xp

Currently our application installs as a current user, and this is all hunky dory, but our app does require a few dependencies (.NET 3.5, ReportViewer, SQLCE), and all these require admin or elevated rights to install.

Now on Vista/Windows 7, this is not a problem. But what does one do besides getting someone else to login and install the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Lot of background information is missing from this, but, to put it bluntly, you can't/shouldn't.  That is exactly why such security policies were implemented, so that changes can not be made to a system without proper authorization and privileges.

Even if you are able to get around the issue one time, you'll still have to deal with it if you come across a customer environment with very stringent security policies in place.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MSI feature [Administrative Install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367541(VS.85).aspx).  This feature was designed for exactly the scenario you describe.  In a nutshell, an administrator can "bless" an installation package with his Admin credentials.  The non-admin users get a link to the installer, (could be a shortcut, a COM interface, a file type association, etc.) which when run performs the install with the administrator's credentials.  Everything else, however, takes place with the user's credentials.